# Exposing Prometheus metrics in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, prometheus, monitoring, metrics

It looks like there's loads of composer plugins to do this but nothing in active development with commits since the release of Laravel 9. Is there a popular go-to option for this?

(Almost posted this in software recommendations - let me know if that's a more appropriate place for it.)

Comment: If you are asking for a recommendation of a tool or lib, then yes, please delete it here, for being off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one https://github.com/arquivei/laravel-prometheus-exporter is relatively alive and even declare Laravel 9 support.

It is actually for Laravel\Lumen but can be used as a reference point

Comment: Haha committed two weeks after I asked and about one week after I just made my own. Thanks though - this is probably a lot better than what I have.

Comment: Actually I figured out it is for Laravel\Lumen so probably won't work for vanilla Laravel from the scratch, probbaly building something on top of https://github.com/promphp/prometheus_client_php would be a good idea, at least you won't be limited by a few guys forgetting to support their fork :)

Comment: Ah OK well I'll leave that as the answer anyway because I don't think any others are incoming! Still helps the Lumen users and a potential starting point for classic Laravel users in the comment. Cheers :-)